# How does the Gmail Android app do the webview-header-overlay magic for the mail-conversation view?

Tags: android, webkit, webview, scroll, overlay

Using [hierarchyviewer](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-ui.html) on the Gmail conversation view shows an interesting and unusual layout hierarchy:

- **All** messages in a single conversation are rendered in a **single** WebView (specifically a `com.google.android.gm.CustomWebView`, seen on the left). Only the body of the messages is rendered - **the spaces where the headers would go are left blank**.
- On top of the WebView is overlaid a `com.google.android.gm.MessageHeaderScrollView` (seen on the right) which uses a `HybridConversationScrollContainer` to position a `MessageHeaderView` in the correct position for each message in the conversation view.

[image: CustomWebView] <-> [image: MessageHeaderScrollView]

So, how (and why) is this achieved? Is it something that an Android developer could & should aspire to re-create in their own apps?

Obviously the probable *why* is performance - WebView uses the fast native WebKit rendering of the message text, and a single WebView is probably more efficient than a separate WebView for each message. If anyone has seen any good blogposts on the performance benefits of this I'd be interested.

Yet there's an obvious complexity cost to this approach (against naively using an [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) with some TextViews inside it or whatever) - the `HybridConversationScrollContainer` has to somehow work out where the message headers should go over the web-rendering, in order to position it's `MessageHeaderViews` correctly. What I'd like to know is: *How* does it work out those offsets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incidentally, the only approach I can think of is javascript-based - use javascript in the WebView to gather the header coordinates, and then use `WebView.addJavascriptInterface()` to pass those coordinates on to Java and the `HybridConversationScrollContainer`. I haven't tried doing this myself though so I'm not sure if it could actually work.

There *is* a short post on the android Developer blog talking about the `addJavascriptInterface()` method:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2008/09/using-webviews.html

It would be wonderful if `MessageHeaderScrollView` could be released as an open-source library - I'd use it! - but seeing as the Gmail app is closed, it doesn't seem immediately likely.

Comment: Can you please help me more on this? I am trying to implement this from long time.

Comment: 4 years later and still lots of us struggling to achieve this type of thing on Android.  I understand Google doesn't want lots of GMail clones out there, but if they want more good apps on their store, they should help us with some robust ways to mix native UI and HTML -- there is a huge need.