# Listview with webview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-webview

i'm trying to create a ListView with a Webview inside, but the app shows nothing.
Here my Code:

The MainActivity where I set the CustomAdapter

```
    public class Web_in_list1Activity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView2);
    ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this);

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
    }
```

getView of the CustomAdapter
Here I get the Layout for the ListView and ste the URL for the Webview

```
    public View getView(int arg0, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    LayoutInflater inflater =  context.getLayoutInflater();
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);

    WebView wv = (WebView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            wv.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

            convertView.setTag(wv);

    return convertView;
}
```

main.xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

     <LinearLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/listView2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
     </LinearLayout>
```

listitem.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


    <WebView  

            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

CLOSED!
PROBLEM SOLVED WITH A SCROLLVIEW

Comment: I have a feeling that this is one of the more creative ways to discharge your battery. :D *(but sadly I don't see why it doesn't work here)*

Comment: haha good feeling :D no seriously...i try to make a webview where I can add a View, which scrolls with the content of the WebView, so I try to make a listview with a header...another idea how I can solve my problem?

Comment: anyone a idea? pls help.

Comment: ok problem solved...i used a scrollview!

Comment: I think scroll view is not a solution if there's so long list :). Because ListView is designed for memory efficiency, the list items' views is used only for visible ones.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> i'm trying to create a ListView with a Webview inside

You cannot reliably put scrollable things inside of other scrollable things. Hence, you cannot reliably:

- Put a `WebView` in a `ListView` row
- Put a `ScrollView` in a `ListView` row
- Put a `WebView` in a `ScrollView`
- Put a `ListView` in a `ScrollView`

Moreover, a `WebView` is a very heavyweight widget and is not designed to have lots of copies floating around. Please consider using `TextView` for lightweight HTML rendering.

Comment: How is the GMail app doing it? Are you saying they are not having any native controls at all? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301246/how-does-the-gmail-android-app-do-the-webview-header-overlay-magic-for-the-mail

Comment: @Enigma: You might consider reading the question and answer that you linked to, as it answers your question.

Comment: @CommonsWare - What are your views on using WebViews inside the newer RecyclerViews from performance point of view? Even though WebViews are heavy components, they would be part of Holders which would be reused.

Comment: @Chebyr: The issue about scrollable things in scrollable things may still be an issue, depending on the content in the `WebView` and the direction of scrolling of the `RecyclerView`. The issue about weight will depend on how many `WebViews` might be visible or cached. So, for example, using [`RecyclerViewPager`](https://github.com/lsjwzh/RecyclerViewPager) (a `ViewPager` replacement based on `RecyclerView`) with `WebViews` is probably OK, as they will have perpendicular scrolling/swiping and few `WebViews`. A vertical list with lots of `WebViews` may still be trouble, though.

Comment: CommonsWare solution may have been valid 5 years ago but it certainly isn't true anymore. I and many others have no problems embedding webviews into listviews or other scrollable containers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it worked for me.

```
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        String Vurl = "your URL";
        ViewHolder holder;

        mHandler = new Handler();
        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);


            holder.browser = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webview);

            view.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        holder.browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        holder.browser.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

        holder.browser.loadUrl(Vurl);
        holder.browser.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_INSET);


        return view;

    }

    class ViewHolder {
        WebView browser;
    }
}
```