# How do I display a list of heavily formatted text fragments in Android?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-view

I am developing an Android App for a community forum and am struggling with how to display the conversations. One page consists of 30 posts, to which I am bound per API. The posts contain text with the usual formatting (strong, underline, etc.), but may also contain tables, blockquotes and some other blocklike elements. Most elements can be nested, e.g., the `<table>` block may be surrounded by `<strong>` tags. Each post consists of a header with a static layout and non-formatted text.

The approach I used so far is rendering the whole conversation as HTML in a `WebView`. This is very easy, since I can use CSS and Javascript to customize it and it is straightforward to implement. However, this method has some drawbacks:

- `WebView`s are very heavy. Especially when animated gifs or large images are contained, scrolling and interaction becomes less smooth even on fast phones.
- Interaction with the App is somewhat limited; It is much more difficult to scroll to a specific position when the View is rendered; mostly, because this must be handled via Javascript and one never knows about render times etc.
- Buttons, Long touches, link clicks etc. must all be handled via Javascript, which, especially for the different touch events, is kind of cumbersome.

Now I was thinking of different ways to handle this. Options are the following:

- Build a dynamical View hirarchy. All the inline tags could be `Spans` in `TextViews`, the rest would be some specific layouts. Disadvantages: I would have a large number of views on the screen, it is hard to generate the hierarchy properly and it is hard to, for example, have some block views be surrounded with `<strong>` tags.
- A hybrid view, as the [Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301246/how-does-the-gmail-android-app-do-the-webview-header-overlay-magic-for-the-mail) uses it. This also would need a lot of Javascript do calculate distances etc. and it is less flexible when the layout changes during display.
- A `ListView` of 30 `WebViews`. WebViews are very heavy, so this may be unwise as well.

What is the best way to solve this? How are other, similar Apps solving this problem? Is there any way to make the Javascript stuff in `WebViews` more reliable and stable?

Answer (score 1):

I think you hit the nail on the head with building the view hierarchy. I would probably create a custom list item layout for the rows, although a multiline text view would probably do the trick. Then to process the HTML you could use the [Html](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html) `Spanned` builder. You would need to create a [Html.TagHandler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.TagHandler.html) to deal with any html tags that the builder doesn't support though.

Comment: I am not sure whether you understood the question correctly. The ListView is not the problem; The thing is that I would need to dynamically assemble the row views from html code. This seems like quite some overhead and may even be slower than just putting together some html and displaying it in a WebView... 

I do know about the TagHandler, though. Thanks!